# c# MVC different behvior on live server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, iis

Okay so I have some code that sends emails. In the email subject I need to include a date value saved as Datetime. When running the application from the development sever locally the date is added to the subject line sucessfully, as 12-05-2021. However when the same code runs on the server the date is added as 12-05-2021 00:00:00. I'm removing the time with with `contractDate.ToString().Replace("00:00:00","")`. I'm not sure how to debug this. The web app is deployed on IIS 2012 server. There's no errors in the logs, and everything works okay except this subject line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting the date this way: `contractDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver! I'm surprised something like this could have caused an issue.